# type-level programming in Scala with peano arithmetic

Tags: scala, generic-programming, type-level-computation

I'm studying type-leve programming in scala from https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-4d-peano-arithmetic/.
And get error in Mod

```
type Mod[A <: Nat, B <: Nat] = A#FoldR[_0, Nat, ModFold[B]]
type ModFold[By <: Nat] = Fold[Nat, Nat] {
    type Wrap[Acc <: Nat] = By#Compare[Acc]#eq
    type Apply[N <: Nat, Acc <: Nat] = Wrap[Succ[Acc]]#IF[_0, Succ[Acc], Nat]
}

toBoolean[ Eq[ Mod[_4, _6], _3] ]


Error:(110, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter b:  BoolRep[Eq[Mod[_4,_6],_3]]
    toBoolean[ Eq[ Mod[_4, _6], _3] ]
             ^
```

After that, I try some expression in scala repl,

```
implicitly[ModFold[_2]#Wrap[Succ[_1]]#IF[_0, Succ[_1], Nat] <:< Nat]
// correct

implicitly[ModFold[_2]#Apply[_1, _2] <:< Nat]
// error,  Cannot prove that Bool.this.IF[_0,Succ[_2],Nat] <:< Nat.
```

from my view, the first expression is just the second expression expand in manual.

How dose those happen and how can I get those correct?

I'm using scala 2.11

Comment: Try comparing `:t ModFold[_2]#Wrap[Succ[_1]]#IF[_0, Succ[_1], Nat]` with `:t ModFold[_2]#Apply[_1, _2]`. That should tell you what's different about the two types.